# Sort-Object - differences when using console vs .ps1 file

Tags: powershell

When running .ps1 file the sizes are sorted alphabetically (mixing MB and KB).

But when running in the console directly, it correctly sorts by folder size.

Both running on the same server.

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity mailbox@domain.org | Sort-Object Foldersize -Descending | Format-Table folderpath, foldersize
```

**Solution:** turns out it had to do with using a Remote shell. Remote shell returns FolderSize as System.String rather than Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize

Comment: Is anything else different - remoting, particularly, or launching from a cmd prompt or anything?

Comment: Try `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity mailbox@domain.org | Select-Object -Property folderpath, foldersize | Sort-Object -Property Foldersize -Descending`

Comment: Same issue. Works perfectly in Powershell, but not in PS1 file or Powershell ISE